# Setting a NOT NULL constraint on a many-to-many relationship in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have two models related via an association model, all defined using SQLAlchemy's `declarative_base()`.

```
class P(Base):
    p_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo = Column(String)
    bar = Column(String)

class Q(Base):
    q_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    x = Column(String)
    y = Column(String)

class PQ(Base):
    p_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, ForeignKey('p.p_id', match='FULL', primary_key=True)
    q_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, ForeignKey('q.q_id', match='FULL', primary_key=True)
    additional_data = Column(String)

    p = relationship('P', backref='qs')
    q = relationship('Q', backref='ps')
```

Now this works as expected, except that I additionally want to enforce that each `P` *must* be associated with at least one `Q`

```
 p = P()
 p.p_id = 123
 p.save()  # this should throw an exception saying that some constraint is being violated
 session.rollback()
 q = Q()
 q.q_id = 789
 p.qs = [q]
 p.save()  # this should work
```

How can I enforce this using SQLAlchemy?

Comment: "exception saying that some constraint is being violated": note that this isn't enforceable with sql. best you can do is some python level validation, though i'm not sure sqla can do that

Comment: It's actually trivial to do within Python - but are you telling me that I can't enforce a NOT NULL on a foreign key in SQL?

Comment: that's not what i'm saying. i'm saying that with m2m relationships as in your model above, you can't have sql enforce that each P is related to at least one Q

Comment: To expand on what @second was saying, there is no foreign key from P -> Q or P -> PQ.  Instead there are FKs from PQ-> P and PQ -> Q.  There is no column to apply NOT NULL to.  You could add a foreign key to P referencing Q directly and specify that as NOT NULL.  Personally, I would just maintain the check in Python.